# Making simple class constructor PHP?

Tags: php, function

I have one function like this

```
function display ($name, $username)
{
 $final = $name.$username;
return $final
}
```

I have made just very simple function, to display what i need
I sometimes i have problem, when i dont have all constructors, like $name
If i call function like this

```
$total =display($name,$username);
```

All is ok, but what if i dont have etc. $name and i want to call function to get me back the results something like this

```
$total=display($username);
```

When i do this i got error, how to prevent error and let function to do job with only one parametar?

Comment: You probably want to use [default arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

Comment: Can you please give me and example?

Comment: Alternatively, pass it `null` for `$name`.

Comment: @Gorostas There are plenty examples provided in the link!

Comment: @Gorostas See the page I linked. It has plenty of examples, such as http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-157

Comment: Please can all answers be posted in answer that i can vote?

Comment: @Gorostas This question is probably a duplicate of another anyways. It won't do any good to provide answers when the question is to be put on hold.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Txanks, for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a default parameter:

```
function display ($name, $username = "")
{
 $final = $name.$username;
return $final
}
```

now when you call `display("abc")` it will return "abc", and if you call `display("abc", "def")` it will return "abcdef".

Comment: Is it "" sam as NULL?

Comment: You mean if i call function like this $total=display($name, $username); It will override the "" and insert my data?

Comment: yes, it will overwrite the "". The "" will only be used if no second argument is provided.

Answer (score 1):

As @Waleed commented, you can use default arguments like this:

```
function display($name, $username = null)
{
    if ($username !== null) {
        $name .= $username;
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: Or, just `$username = ''` and avoid the `if`-statement.